# Insert regression line equation automatically for multiple groups

Tags: graph, sas, regression, linear-regression

I would like to insert automatically regression line equation into graph produced either by `proc sgplot` or directly by `proc reg` by groups.

For example, I am running regression for each group (originally 11 groups) and time period (15 years):

```
proc reg data=HAVE;
by time group;
   model Y= X;
   ods output ParameterEstimates=PE fitstatistics=FS;
run;
```

I found the code example how to include the regression equation [here](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_templt_a0000000056.htm).

But I cannot figure out how to do it automatically for so many groups (graphs)?

Appreciate any suggestions and comments.

Comment: I think you would need to make 11 graphs separately (in which case you could either write 11 sgplots, or better make a GTL template where the parameters are provided through the SGRENDER call.

Comment: Ok, thanks, Joe, for your comment.